# Semáforo: Problemas na detecção de deadlock

Tags: java

Fiz uma pesquisa por aqui e não encontrei nada que finalizasse minhas dúvidas, com isso, espero que alguém possa me ajudar. Vou colocar o código aqui, pra que vocês visualizem melhor o problema. Ah, qualquer sugestão de organização do código e sobre quem tem responsabilidade de quê é muito bem vinda também.

O problema é o seguinte:

Os processos podem usar quantos recursos quiserem, mas não pode ser recursos que já estão em uso ou que o processo já utilizou antes. Em um dado momento, o código do jeito que está, entra em *deadlock* e apenas um recurso é liberado, depois ele permanece na verificação.

```
package com.alane.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Processo extends Thread{
    private int id;
    private int tempoSolicitacao;
    private int tempoUtilizacao;
    private SistemaOperacional sistemaOperacional;
    private ArrayList<Recurso> recursosEmUsoNoProcesso;
    private static final int MAX_PROCESSOS = 10;
    //private static Semaphore totalDeProcessos = new Semaphore(MAX_PROCESSOS);
    private static Semaphore mutexAdd = new Semaphore(1);
    private static Semaphore mutexRemove = new Semaphore(1);
    private ArrayList<Integer> memoriaDeProcessos;


    public Processo(SistemaOperacional so, int id, int tempoSolicitacao, int tempoUtilizacao) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sistemaOperacional = so;
        this.tempoSolicitacao = tempoSolicitacao;
        this.tempoUtilizacao = tempoUtilizacao;
        //this.mutexControleDisponibilidade = 
        this.recursosEmUsoNoProcesso = new ArrayList<Recurso>();
        this.memoriaDeProcessos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /*
         * Aqui a gente vai dormir o tempo da solicitação. 
         * A cada dormida a gente solicita novo recurso e 

         * iniciamos uma nova Thread que conta o tempo de 
         * utilização. Apos essa contagem o recurso deixa
         * de ser usado e fica livre. 
         */
        super.run();
        do{
            try {
                Thread usando = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            int number = solicitarRecurso();
                            System.out.println(id + " Solicitei o number + " +number);
                            Recurso recurso = sistemaOperacional.retornaRecurso(number);
                            System.out.println(id +" Que é o recurso : " + recurso.getNome());
                            mutexAdd.acquire();
                            if(sistemaOperacional.verificaDisponibilidade(recurso) && verificaMemoriaDeProcessos(recurso)) {
                                usarRecurso(recurso);
                            } 
                            mutexAdd.release();
                            sleep(tempoUtilizacao*1000);
                            //mutexControleDisponibilidade.release();
                            mutexRemove.acquire();
                                liberarRecurso(recurso);
                            mutexRemove.release();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                usando.start();
                sleep(this.tempoSolicitacao*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while(true);

    }


    public void usarRecurso(Recurso recurso) {
        sistemaOperacional.getRecursosEmUso().add(recurso);
        recursosEmUsoNoProcesso.add(recurso);
        memoriaDeProcessos.add(recurso.getId());
        System.out.println(id +" Oba, to usando recurso "+recurso.getNome());
    }

    public void liberarRecurso(Recurso recurso) {
        sistemaOperacional.getRecursosEmUso().remove(sistemaOperacional.getRecursosEmUso().indexOf(recurso));
        recursosEmUsoNoProcesso.remove(recursosEmUsoNoProcesso.indexOf(recurso));
        System.out.println(id +" Liberar o recurso:  " + recurso.getNome());

    }
    public int solicitarRecurso() {
        //this.sistemaOperacional.getRecursosDisponiveis().size();
        int number = new Random().nextInt(this.sistemaOperacional.getRecursos().size());
        return number;

    }

    public boolean verificaMemoriaDeProcessos(Recurso recurso) {
        if(memoriaDeProcessos.contains(recurso.getId())) {
            System.out.println("Vish, você já usou o recurso: " + recurso.getNome());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTempoSolicitacao() {
        return tempoSolicitacao;
    }

    public void setTempoSolicitacao(int tempoSolicitacao) {
        this.tempoSolicitacao = tempoSolicitacao;
    }

    public int getTempoUtilizacao() {
        return tempoUtilizacao;
    }

    public void setTempoUtilizacao(int tempoUtilizacao) {
        this.tempoUtilizacao = tempoUtilizacao;
    }


    public SistemaOperacional getSistemaOperacional() {
        return sistemaOperacional;
    }

    public void setSistemaOperacional(SistemaOperacional sistemaOperacional) {
        this.sistemaOperacional = sistemaOperacional;
    }
}
```

```
package com.alane.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Recurso {
    int id;
    public static int recursosInstanciados = 0;
    String nome;
    static final int MAX_RECURSOS = 10;
    public Recurso(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = recursosInstanciados;
        recursosInstanciados++;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome(){
        return this.nome;
    }
    public static ArrayList<Recurso>recursosDefault(){
        ArrayList<Recurso> recursos = new ArrayList<Recurso>();

        recursos.add(new Recurso("Teclado"));
        recursos.add(new Recurso("Mouse"));
        //recursos.add(new Recurso("Placa de video"));
        //recursos.add(new Recurso("DVD"));
        //recursos.add(new Recurso("Pendrive1"));
        //recursos.add(new Recurso("Fax Molden"));
        //recursos.add(new Recurso("Impressora"));
        return recursos;
    }
}
```

```
package com.alane.so;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SistemaOperacional extends Thread {
    private ArrayList<Processo> processos;
    private ArrayList<Processo> processosDeadlock;
    private int tempoDeVerificacao;
    private ArrayList<Recurso> recursos;
    public ArrayList<Recurso> getRecursosEmUso() {
        return recursosEmUso;
    }

    public void setRecursosEmUso(ArrayList<Recurso> recursosEmUso) {
        this.recursosEmUso = recursosEmUso;
    }
    private ArrayList<Recurso> recursosEmUso;

    public SistemaOperacional(){
        this.recursosEmUso = new ArrayList<Recurso>();
        this.recursos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.recursos = Recurso.recursosDefault();           
    }

    public Recurso retornaRecurso(int number) {
        return this.getRecursos().get(number);
    }

    public boolean verificaDisponibilidade(Recurso recurso) {
        if (this.getRecursosEmUso().contains(recurso)) {
            System.out.println("Vish, esta usando o :" +recurso.getNome());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Processo> getProcessos() {
        return processos;
    }
    public void setProcessos(ArrayList<Processo> processos) {
        this.processos = processos;
    }
    public ArrayList<Processo> getProcessosDeadlock() {
        return processosDeadlock;
    }
    public void setProcessosDeadlock(ArrayList<Processo> processosDeadlock) {
        this.processosDeadlock = processosDeadlock;
    }
    public int getTempoDeVerificacao() {
        return tempoDeVerificacao;
    }
    public void setTempoDeVerificacao(int tempoDeVerificacao) {
        this.tempoDeVerificacao = tempoDeVerificacao;
    }
    public ArrayList<Recurso> getRecursos() {
        return recursos;
    }
    public void setRecursos(ArrayList<Recurso> recursosDisponiveis) {
        this.recursos = recursosDisponiveis;
    }
}
```

```
package com.alane.so;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SistemaOperacional so = new SistemaOperacional();
        Processo p = new Processo(so, 1, 1, 5);
        Processo p1 = new Processo(so, 2, 1, 5);
        p.start();
        //p1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Já usou o debugger da sua IDE?
Você ta usando esses printlns ai pra saber, em tempo de execução, oque tá acontecendo. Eu te aconselho a usar o debugger.

 Achar bugs em programas com threads é bem complicado só olhando o código, se você debuggar isso daí vai achar rápido.

Comment: Na verdade, usar o debug para  um programa com threads  não dá muito certo. A IDE normalmente se perde. Em outros casos, quando você está no debug a aplicação funciona corretamente e quando você executa dá o erro. Nesses casos o ideal é debugar realmente usando prints.